# My first idea for a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I keep thinking that there should be a .id in jQuery instead of .attr('id').

Q: How do you write a plug-in, so that myObject.id returns myObject.attr('id')?

Comment: Your thinking about it the wrong way. You should solve your `.attr("id")` with `[0].id` rather then `.id()`

Comment: You're right. jQuery is too hard to use and is super verbose. We *need* more plugins like this.

Comment: Now come on!  What wrong with $(this).id()?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn To use your argument, what's wrong with `$(this).attr('id')`?

Comment: Because whenever I type in .attr('id'), I always think "Isn't there a .id() that I should be using?"

Comment: No, there isn't. jQuery already does everything for you. Why do you take a useless shortcut on a giant shortcut? It doesn't actually do anything that isn't already provided right inside the jQuery core. You're basically making a function called `all`, which calls `jQuery.each`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sake of argument here's how you would do it.

```
// extend jQuery object with your id
$.fn.id = function() {
    // return the id of the first DOM element.
    return this[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Isn't 'this' a jquery object? And should be this.attr('id') instead?

Comment: My eyes must be playing tricks on me because I swear it was this.id and not this[0].id

Comment: Thanks Raynos!  This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can already do something like this

```
$(".classDiv")[0].id
```

or write your own `.id()` plugins :)

Comment: How do I write a .id() plugin to return $(this)[0].id?

Comment: Look at Raynos answer. He is almost there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are specifically interested only for "id" or not, I am extending your question below.

considering the following fragment:

```
<p id="hello" another="ok" class="voila">Hello World</p>
```

I want to use:

```
alert( $("#hello").another ); // -> ok
alert( $("#hello").class ); // -> voila
```

currently we need to use $`("#hello").attr("another")` because `$("#hello")[0].another` will not work.